# Transfer json array from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to transfer a json array from PHP to JS

```html
 <?php
//controllo se sono presenti i parametri
if(isset($_GET['id_utente']) && isset($_GET['longitude']) && isset($_GET['latitude']))
{
//Recupero il valore dei parametri
$id_utente = $_GET['id_utente'];
$longitude= $_GET['longitude'];
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "realegr";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "my_realegr";



// Create connection,
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);


// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully\n";




// Insert Data
$sql = "INSERT INTO Prova (id_utente, latitude, longitude)
VALUES ('" . $id_utente . "', '" . $longitude . "', '" . $latitude . "')
";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully\n\r";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
 
// Execute query and save it in result
$sql = "SELECT  latitude,longitude FROM Prova ORDER by reg_date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
   /* while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "latitude: " . $row["longitude"]. " - longitude: " . $row["latitude"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
      */   
         
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
         echo json_encode([
           'status' => true,
           'latitude' => $row["longitude"],
           'longitude' => $row["latitude"],
         ]);
    

   

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   
   

        <script async defer 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBkEtPH07_xBVh8dWBzCQYtWimkOUnPGMQ&callback=initMap"></script>
    
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>    
    
    <script>
function initMap(){
  


     var $request = $.get('http://realegr.altervista.org/PopolamentoTabella.php');
     $request.done( function(data) {
     alert(data);
          var pasedData = JSON.parse(data);          
          var longi = parseFloat(pasedData.longitude);
          var lati = parseFloat(pasedData.latitude);
 
      
     var uluru = {lat: lati, lng: longi};
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              zoom: 4,
              center: uluru
                                                                   });
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: uluru,
              map: map
                                          });
              
})
}
</script>
    
    

  </body>
</html>
```

The php script seems work well.It updates the DB and echo the JSON array,as it should.
But when I try to load the Maps it gives me some error:
[image]
Beside in console I have this:
[image]

further information:evry time I send data to DB( with a get request), the php script has to send (only)gps coordinates to JS,to show them on a google maps

Comment: FYI : If you're going to return JSON to an ajax request, you have to return JSON, and only JSON. You have conditions and echo statements that output other than things than valid JSON.

Comment: As I can see at your error message - it asks for integer value for column "id_utente", but instead you're trying to insert something different.

Comment: The posted error has to do with the fact that the `GET` values expected in the PHP code, which again is used to insert data into the DB, isn't correct. This isn't really suprising, seeing as the `$.get` request doesn't seem to be sending any data at all?

Comment: it usually isn't a good idea to echo such a detailed error message back to the client. You're giving away the structure of your DB, and possibly other info which could be of value to a malicious user. Instead send a HTTP 500 (internal server error) response and a generic message, and log the real exception to a private log file on the server which you can check for debugging information. And also as others have pointed out, the error message isn't being sent in JSON format, which is causing jQuery to have a hiccup when it tries to parse it as JSON.

Comment: And the root cause of the error is that you're not sending any data to the server in the GET request, and the server is not properly validating that (it checks the GET values using isset, but only for the purpose of creating some variables. If they aren't set, it still tries to carry on with the rest of the code regardless, and of course the database cannot cope with empty variables. Instead it should send a 400 Bad Request response, preferably containing some JSON object which details the validation errors, so that the caller can fix them.

Comment: And the last sin on top of all of that faulty logic is that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: Once you sort all that, it will still fail to parse the JSON response because of the totally unnecessary `echo "New record created successfully\n\r"` line. Again this is not JSON-encoded, and also it's totally superfluous in a machine-to-machine interaction such as this (an ajax request comes from the browser, not direct from a human, and in this case is dealing with data not human-readable text) - the client should assume the requested operation was successful unless you return a HTTP response code which indicates an error condition (e.g. 400, 500, 403, 404 and similar).

Comment: One last thing - it seems like the last SELECT statement is a bit pointless - it just reproduces the same data which the user inserted into the database (hopefully, unless there are lots of simultaneous requests, in which case, because you didn't use transactions, it might not be). You can skip this entirely and, assuming the INSERT does not fail, just return the latitude and longitude originally given in the request. In fact, you needn't even do that, because the caller already knows the values. All they need is the HTTP 200 OK response to know that the INSERT succeeded.

Comment: So in fact a large amount of your code is not really necessary, and some things which _are_ necessary, i.e. sending the latitude and longitude values to the server, validating them properly, and sending appropriate error message codes, are the only bits you haven't implemented. What a mess.

Comment: @ADyson - couldn't you have posted that as an answer? Now I have to upvote 6 comments ;) All good points, by the way!

Comment: @PetervanderWal lol thanks. It probably doesn't constitute an answer - I've just pointed out the flaws, rather than fixing them. If I get time I'll produce a version that might actually work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your 'PopolamentoTabella.php' to this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "YOURUSERNAME";
$password = "YOURPASSWORD";
$dbname = "YOUR DB";

// Create connection,
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//echo "Connected successfully\n";
//controllo se sono presenti i parametri
if (isset($_GET['id_utente']) && isset($_GET['longitude']) && isset($_GET['latitude'])) {
//Recupero il valore dei parametri
    $id_utente = $_GET['id_utente'];
    $longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
    $latitude = $_GET['latitude'];

// Insert Data
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Prova (id_utente, latitude, longitude)
VALUES ('" . $id_utente . "', '" . $longitude . "', '" . $latitude . "')
";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        //echo "New record created successfully\n\r";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} else {
// Execute query and save it in result
    $sql = "SELECT  latitude,longitude FROM Prova ORDER by reg_date DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
//if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    /* while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "latitude: " . $row["longitude"]. " - longitude: " . $row["latitude"]. "<br>";
      }
      } else {
      echo "0 results";
      }
     */

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo json_encode([
        'status' => true,
        'latitude' => $row["longitude"],
        'longitude' => $row["latitude"],
    ]);
}
//echo $longitude; 
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```